# Last 5 related records for multiple records

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a MySQL database with a structure like this...

Site has many Sensors
Sensors has many SensorReadings

I want to get all Sensors for a Site and the last 5 SensorReadings for all those Sensors. I suspect I'm going to have to do something with a stored procedure and temporary tables (if they even exist in MySQL.

Comment: Thanks guys, I've not had chance to test any of these answers yet, I'll hopefully get time in the next few days and accept one as the answer. Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly [Something like](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/02/how-to-number-rows-in-mysql/)...

```
SELECT reading,
       date
FROM   (select sensor_id,
               reading,
               date,
               @num := if(@sensor_id = sensor_id, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,
               @sensor_id := sensor_id                         as dummy
        from   sensor_readings
        order  by sensor_id,
                  date desc) T
WHERE  row_number<=5
```

Please give your actual table structure(s) in your question.

Comment: This doesn't work if there are only readings for one sensor. I'll post some scripts later and link to them in the question.

Comment: Also, if I make this into a stored procedure, the first time I run it it returns everything in the table the second time it's fine.

Comment: @BenCr - Strange. I have seen another version of this technique that puts the variables inside a derived table. Maybe that is to avoid this sort of issue. Will just try and find an example.

Comment: @Ben - Found one here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832569/select-n-records-for-each-category-and-order-by-x/3832701#3832701

Comment: @Martin, I can't see why thats different. maybe the parameters need initialising in a sproc?

Answer (score 1):

Full example using MySQL variables.  For brevity, this displays the top 2 readings per sensor.

```
drop table if exists Sensors;
create table Sensors (Id int);
insert Sensors (id) values (1), (2), (3);

drop table if exists SensorReadings;
create table SensorReadings (SensorId int, RecordDate date);
insert SensorReadings (SensorId, RecordDate) values 
    (1, '2011-01-01'),
    (1, '2011-01-02'),
    (1, '2011-01-03'),
    (2, '2011-01-01'),
    (2, '2011-01-02'),
    (2, '2011-01-03');


set @num = -1;
set @SensorId = -1;

select  *
from    Sensors s
join    (
        select  *
        ,       @num := if(@SensorId = SensorId, @num + 1, 1) as rn
        ,       @SensorId := SensorId
        from    SensorReadings sr
        order by
                SensorId
        ,       RecordDate desc
        ) as numbered
on      numbered.SensorId = s.Id
where   numbered.rn < 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Andomar dump

```
select * from SensorReadings as t1
where (select count(*) from SensorReadings as t2
       where t1.sensorid = t2.sensorid and t2.recordDate > t1.recordDate) <2
```