# Selecting two different random entries for each category with mySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, left-join

I have a table which looks something like:

```
table: Q
---------------------------
|question| scope |  type  |
---------------------------
|  this  |   A   |   1    |
|  that  |   A   |   1    |
|  them  |   A   |   1    |
---------------------------
|  this  |   A   |   2    |
|  that  |   A   |   2    |
|  them  |   A   |   2    |
---------------------------
|  this  |   B   |   1    |
|  that  |   B   |   1    |
|  them  |   B   |   1    |
---------------------------
```

I need given a scope, I need to extract two entries from each type. If scope is A, a possible solution could be:

```
---------------------------
|  this  |   A   |   1    |
|  them  |   A   |   1    |
---------------------------
|  that  |   A   |   2    |
|  this  |   A   |   2    |
---------------------------
```

I'm currently using the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT tmp.question, tmp.type, tmp.scope
FROM Q
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT * FROM Q ORDER BY RAND( )
)tmp ON ( Q.type = tmp.type AND tmp.scope = 'A' ) 
GROUP BY tmp.type
ORDER BY Q.type
```

However this only returns one entry per type and for some reason a NULL row.
My question is therefore how to optimize the statement to return two rows and eliminate the NULL one?

Comment: I'll ask you to edit your question.  I think you're asking for *two*, *different*, *randomly chosen*, entries from each distinct `type`.  Correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can change rank from 2 to whatever you want to get for each category.

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f3946/86

try this:

```
  SELECT x.question,
       x.scope,
       x.type
  FROM (

    SELECT bp.question, bp.scope, bp.type, 
    CASE WHEN bp.type = @type 
         THEN @rownum := @rownum + 1
         ELSE @rownum := 1
         END AS rank,
    @type := bp.type
FROM (select * from Q order by rand()) bp
JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0, @type := NULL) r
WHERE bp.scope = 'A'
ORDER BY type
    ) x
 WHERE x.rank <= 2
order by x.type
```

Note: I used an old answer and improved for randomizing.
Old answer I got help is:
[Select N records for each category and order by X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832569/select-n-records-for-each-category-and-order-by-x)

Comment: Wow thats a complicated statement, but it dose the trick! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

**[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ff05c/10)**:

```
(
  SELECT question, scope, type FROM Q
  WHERE  scope = 'A' AND type = 1
  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2
)
UNION
(
  SELECT question, scope, type FROM Q
  WHERE  scope = 'A' AND type = 2
  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2
)
```

Comment: @AndreasJarbol I think this is the case. I obviously misunderstood.